# Windshield vent

Tags: bmw, damage, windshield, vents

I just bloody spilled a full medium cup of hot chocolate down my 2002 bmw sport station wagons windshield vent. What do I do to clean and what should I look out for damage? Help me please. I am not sure as of what to expect.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know how BMW's are put together, but will bet you're going to be looking at a complete tear down of the HVAC ducting to get it completely clean. This would be a *very* daunting job even for the experienced. Not a lot of fun. Sorry for chocolate mess ... it has to suck.

Comment: Doubt it damaged anything, enjoy the smell for a while then forget it.

Answer (score 1):

A 2002 BMW is a nice classic car. Unfortunately you will have to start dismantling the dashboard starting from the top piece. Usually it's phillips screws, some under little moveable covers. Find a service manual or a Tubevideo. After the top piece is off, you will see the defroster tubes zigzig down toward the heater box.
Push some paper towels in to absorb liquid. Then wiggle out the pipes for thorough cleaning. Those pieces may have a staple where they join, otherwise tape or press-fit. Re-assemble without the staple, just add bits of duct tape to secure each joint.
You may have to remove a couple of vacuum hoses or wiring conectors. Mark the locations before you remove them. Vacuum hoses need a twist, and connectors usually have a push-lever on the side. Use an egg carton to organize the different screws. You mostly want to remove all trace of the hot chocolate before it gets sticky and smelly. If the fluid goes deeper use paper towels followed by wet wipes.

Comment: The mention of "station wagon" has me thinking the "2002" refers to the model year rather than the designation (they didn't do a "wagon" of the 2002) but this answer still applies in general and is a good answer!